# Hdfs text file to parquet format using map reduce job

Tags: java, mapreduce, parquet

I am trying to convert a hdfs text file to Parquet format using map reduce in java. Honestly I am starter of this and am unable to find any direct references.

Should the conversion be textfile --> avro ---> parquet.. ?

Answer (score 11):

A text file (whether in HDFS or not) has no inherent file format.  When using Map/Reduce, you will need an Avro Schema and a mapper function that will parse the input so that you can create an [Avro `GenericRecord`](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/api/java/org/apache/avro/generic/GenericRecord.html).

Your mapper class will look something like this.

```
public class TextToAvroParquetMapper
        extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Void, GenericRecord> {
    private GenericRecord myGenericRecord = new GenericData.Record(mySchema);

    @Override
    protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) {
          // Parse the value yourself here,
          // calling "put" on the Avro GenericRecord,
          // once for each field.  The GenericRecord
          // object is reused for every map call.
          context.write(null, myGenericRecord);
    }
}
```

The input key/value pair types are Hadoop's `LongWritable` and `Text`, and the output key/value pair types are `Void` (null keys) and the Avro `GenericRecord` itself.

In the `run` method, set the `Job` configuration as usual, including the input path, output path, and the mapper class.  Set the number of reduce tasks to 0, because this is a map-only job.

```
job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
```

Set the output format class to `Parquet`'s `AvroParquetOutputFormat` class, which converts the `Avro` `GenericRecord`s you create into the `Parquet` columnar format.  It needs to know your [Avro `Schema`](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/api/java/org/apache/avro/Schema.html).

```
job.setOutputFormatClass(AvroParquetOutputFormat.class);
AvroParquetOutputFormat.setSchema(job, myAvroSchema);
```

Because `AvroParquetOutputFormat` translates an Avro `GenericRecord` into a Parquet `Group` object, you'll need to set the output value class to `Group` (and the output key class to `Void`, as the keys will all be `null`).

```
job.setOutputKeyClass(Void.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(Group.class);
```

Yes, the conversion is textfile -> Avro -> Parquet.  Your `map` method controls the conversion from a textfile to Avro, and `AvroParquetOutputFormat` handles the conversion from Avro to Parquet.

Comment: What if I want to build a schema on the fly ?, How can I  set the schema like below in Driver ? , AvroParquetOutputFormat.setSchema(job, myAvroSchema);